# Rails contact form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, contacts

Trying to get a contact form working on an old project that has been sitting around awhile. I have my contact view and the following for my models, views and controllers. I don't have anything yet for my contact.html.erb file where the form will go. Thanks for any help you can offer.  Instead of telling me how "easy it is" can you actually help me through this? I've been trying and trying on this and have gotten no where.

Model:

```
    class MessagesController < ApplicationController

    def new
    @message = Message.new
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new(message_params)

    if @message.valid?
      MessageMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
      redirect_to contact_path, notice: "Your messages has been sent."
    else
      flash[:alert] = "An error occurred while delivering this message."
      render :new
    end
  end

private



def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:name, :email, :content)
  end

end
```

View: mailer.html.erb

```
 <html>
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
```

Controller:
messages_controller.rb

```
    class MessagesController < ApplicationController

    def new
    @message = Message.new
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new(message_params)

    if @message.valid?
      MessageMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
      redirect_to contact_path, notice: "Your messages has been sent."
    else
      flash[:alert] = "An error occurred while delivering this message."
      render :new
    end
  end

private

  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:name, :email, :content)
  end

end



Messages mailer:

    class MessageMailer < ApplicationMailer


    default from: "Your Mailer <noreply@domain.com>"
    default to: "Your Name <hello@domain.com>"

  def new_message(message)
    @message = message

    mail subject: "Message from #{message.name}"
  end


end
```

Comment: Setting up a form is pretty easy. Read the docs, try something. Then ask if you can't get it to work.

Comment: I've been going through docs, tuts, and more and can't get it:( Believe me when I say it wasn't my first choice to post here.

Comment: well I'm beating my head against the docs and getting no where. I wouldn't have come here if I needed smart ass "go do it yourself answers"

Comment: It's not "being smart ass". Here on SO we usually show what we tried first, and then ask questions on why it isn't working. Seems to me that your real problem is to figure out how to display the template for the messages new action. But it's hard to say on the little information that you provided.